# Invoking closure/method from inside setup method in Groovy

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

For some reason, setup method doesn't recognize the closure that came before it, because when this code gets put into a test suite and ran, it throws 
`MissingMethodException` about the closure I'm trying to call:

```
int initialNumberOfRows = 0

def findRowCount = {

    initialNumberOfRows = 5
}

/**
 * Some methods below are samples for using SetUp/TearDown in a test suite.
 */
/**
 * Sets up test environment.
 */
@SetUp(skipped = false) // Please change skipped to be false to activate this method.
def setUp() {
    //  login and select the test company first
    WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Test Cases/TestCompanySelectGoesToDashboard'), [('shouldLogout') : false, ('shouldCloseBrowser') : false])
    //  go to the "Discounts" page
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('PageMenuOptions/a_Discounts'))
    //  determine the row count
    WebUI.delay(5)
    findRowCount()
}
```

I run that code and get greeted with the following exception message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: DiscountsSuite.findRowCount() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

The closure, as of right now, is a stub, but will be used to get the number of rows, after which we will delete as cleanup for the test suite (I make the rows via the test suite, I gotta clean em up!)